# How to structure a sentence with the pronoun "le" after saying "ne plus avoir lieu d’être" in the previous sentence?

Tags: grammaire

> Je crois qu‘un profond dégoût pour ma propre personne n’a plus lieu d’être.
>
> Peut-être qu’il ne **l**’a jamais **été**...
>
> {or}: Peut-être qu’il ne **l**’a jamais **eu**...

I'm translating some English sentences into French, and  I'm stuck on figuring out how to structure this sentence by using the pronoun "le" that corresponds to the part "n’a plus lieu d’être"  in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

french fellow here ;)

« Peut-être qu’il ne l’a jamais été. » is the correct way. As strange as it could be (even for me), the pronoun refers to *être* and not to *a*.

May I give you a little modification on your first sentence ?

« Je crois qu‘un profond dégoût pour ma personne n’a plus lieu d’être. » -> I deleted *propre* because it was redundant with me *ma*. Your sentence was still correct and would be quite be accepted but it is a style fault.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hi. How do you deal with the following construction, on the other hand? :) « Je crois que je n’ai plus à me sentir redevable. Peut-être que je ne l’a jamais **{???}** »

Comment: « Je crois que je n’ai plus à me sentir redevable. Peut-être que je ne l’ai jamais {été}. » a -> ai and ??? -> été. But... maybe this is not what you meant. If you meant that maybe you were not liable, it is the good sentence. If you meant that maybe you feeled not liable, the correct sentence would be : « Peut-être que je ne me le suis jamais senti ».

Comment: Oh, I'm now talking about a different sentence with a different meaning! :) In order to delve deeper into this grammatical point. Do you think "été" is the one to use in this instance, too?